# knitr: Why can't I see good version of .html file after knitting with .Rmd on GitHub?

Tags: html, github, markdown, rstudio, r-markdown

Rstudio 3.2.4
Windows 10 x64 
Coursera: Reproducible Research

I wrote a .Rmd file and created from it a .html file using knitr via the "Knit HTML" button in the editor.  When I view the .html file on my machine with RStudio it appears how I want (with all output and figures, etc.), but when I upload the directory to GitHub and view the same .html file, I see only HTML code.  I expect to see the nice file I saw in RStudio.

I pushed the entire directory containing all original files.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Knit HTML" button in RStudio was only saving the Rmd and html files, not the intermediate md file.  I ran the `knit` command in the console, which saved the .md file to my working directory.